# How to use 5.16 kernel with Ubuntu 21.10?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kernel, linux-kernel, kubuntu

I'd like to upgrade my kernel to try to fix a persistent issue I have with intermittent freezing.

I've tried manually installing the kernel, but it throws errors during configuration and then upon `sudo apt upgrade` it shows:

```
linux-headers-5.16.0-051600-generic : Depends: libssl3 (>= 3.0.0~~alpha1) but it is not installable
```

**Is this something that can be worked around?**

As it stands my Linux installation is unusable and I've been holding out for this kernel as my last thing to try before being forced back to Windows.

Comment: what specifically do you mean when you say "I've tried manually..."? To me, that sounds like you compiled a kernel from a vanilla source code clone?

Comment: Apologies, was having technical issues which made me make this question less detailed than would be ideal. I installed them by following [9to5linux guide](https://9to5linux.com/how-to-install-linux-kernel-5-16-on-ubuntu-or-linux-mint) using `sudo dpkg -i *.deb` - When that failed I figured I'd try the [`mainline` package](https://github.com/bkw777/mainline) but that wouldn't work because it kept saying I wasn't authorized to run as another user - and failed in some other way when running it as root.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**WARNING: the below method may break your system. You have been warned.**

Ubuntu mainline kernel 5.15.7+ and 5.16 bumps the requirement from `libssl1.1 (>= 1.1.0)` to `libssl3 (>= 3.0.0~~alpha1)`.
You can find the change from the header packages:

```
dpkg -I linux-headers-5.15.6-051506-generic_5.15.6-051506.202112010437_amd64.deb | grep Depends
# Depends: linux-headers-5.15.6-051506, libc6 (>= 2.34), libelf1 (>= 0.142), libssl1.1 (>= 1.1.0), zlib1g (>= 1:1.2.3.3)
dpkg -I linux-headers-5.15.7-051507-generic_5.15.7-051507.202112080459_amd64.deb | grep Depends
# Depends: linux-headers-5.15.7-051507, libc6 (>= 2.34), libelf1 (>= 0.142), libssl3 (>= 3.0.0~~alpha1), zlib1g (>= 1:1.2.3.3)
```

However, the package `libssl3` is only available to Ubuntu 22.04: [libssl3](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&keywords=libssl3&searchon=names) 
Same as its parent package `libssl-dev`, 3.0+ is only available to Ubuntu 22.04 too: [libssl-dev](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&keywords=libssl-dev&searchon=names) 
Therefore, if you're running Ubuntu 21.10 (or below), apt could not find the required libssl3>3.0.

---

You could try manually downloading and installing the package from Ubuntu 22.04:
https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/amd64/libssl3/download

```
# wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl/libssl3_3.0.1-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
# sudo dpkg -i libssl3_3.0.1-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
```

**This is NOT recommended**, as libssl3 is not included in Ubuntu 21.10 or below and Ubuntu 22.04 has not been formally announced until April. However, libssl3 has *almost the same dependency as libssl1.1. There *should* be no issue in using it on Ubuntu 21.10.

---

update

If you really needs these new kernels for **ubuntu 20.04**, download the following debs from ubuntu 22.04:

```
libc6_2.34-0ubuntu3_amd64.deb
libc6-dev_2.34-0ubuntu3_amd64.deb
libc-bin_2.34-0ubuntu3_amd64.deb
libc-dev-bin_2.34-0ubuntu3_amd64.deb
libnsl2_1.3.0-2build1_amd64.deb
libnsl-dev_1.3.0-2build1_amd64.deb
libssl3_3.0.1-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
locales_2.34-0ubuntu3_all.deb
rpcsvc-proto_1.4.2-0ubuntu5_amd64.deb
```

If you trust me, I made a copy to Google Drive: [Google drive](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/17tWzrO1PnyiZ8NkAMoIa9sF3WWy9F9ld?usp=sharing) 
once downloaded all above into one folder, run:

```bsh
# assume root and in this folder
dpkg --force-depends --install *.deb
apt --fix-broken install
```

Your Ubuntu 20.04 is now good for kernel 5.16. It was tested on my server for a week and nothing went wrong.
[image]

**However, it is known that this still NOT works on some systems and breaks them! Use at your own risk! Please wait for Ubuntu 22.04 in the coming April.**

Comment: Manually downloading and installing the package from Ubuntu 22.04 works for me like described in this answer! Had no issue so far.

Comment: Worked great! Thanks very much for taking the time to explain!

Comment: This broke the system for me. please don't do it :'(

Comment: This breaks a few apps, slack included unfortunately

Answer (score 10):

Here's how I got it to work, it's similar to @airium's answer but with the exact commands I used:

- Find the correct kernel version [here](https://kernel.ubuntu.com/%7Ekernel-ppa/mainline/?C=N;O=D); I chose [5.16.11](https://kernel.ubuntu.com/%7Ekernel-ppa/mainline/v5.16.11/).
- Download the generic versions of the driver for your CPU; I had a 64-bit CPU so I got the amd64 ones.

```bsh
mkdir tmp
cd tmp
wget https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.16.11/amd64/linux-headers-5.16.11-051611-generic_5.16.11-051611.202202230823_amd64.deb
wget https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.16.11/amd64/linux-headers-5.16.11-051611_5.16.11-051611.202202230823_all.deb
wget https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.16.11/amd64/linux-image-unsigned-5.16.11-051611-generic_5.16.11-051611.202202230823_amd64.deb
wget https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.16.11/amd64/linux-modules-5.16.11-051611-generic_5.16.11-051611.202202230823_amd64.deb
```

- Install them:

```bsh
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

You'll get an error while installing `..._all.deb` since you've got outdated `libc6` and `libssl3` versions. You'll notice that `sudo apt install libssl3` doesn't work, let's fix that.

- Add the Ubuntu 22.04 repo:

```bsh
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy main"
```

- Now if you try to install `libssl3` it'll tell you to run the following command instead:

```bsh
sudo apt --fix-broken install
```

- Now I think you're good to go, but I also ran the dpkg command once more to make sure:

```bsh
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

No errors!

- Finally, remove the 22.04 repo:

```bsh
sudo add-apt-repository --remove "deb http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy main"
```

---

Edit: If you try to install `libc-dev` and `libc6-dev` in the future, it'll complain about it unless you have the jelly repo. Just add it back, install, and remove.

Answer (score 1):

An alterntive, if you really need a newer version of the kernel and don’t want to install the entire rat’s tail of gcc-11 and libssl3, would be to try **building the kernel yourself,** with your current gcc and the current libssl.

Here’s how that is done:
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/BuildYourOwnKernel

The documentation looks more complicated than it is. In practice, it’s pretty much trivial, because the only hard part is configuring a kernel (differently), which you don’t need here.